# CPU throttling despite turning off the feature in windows & bios

Tags: cpu, bios

I have an ASUS Sabertooth X79 and an i7 3930k overclocked to 4.2 ghz. I set SpeedStep and Throttling off in the BIOS, and also changed my power plan so that both min and max CPU is at 100%. Yet when my computer is in idle, or when I am not doing something CPU intensive, the CPU is at around 3.3ghz. What am I doing wrong? Is there something else in the BIOS I should look for? This throttling wouldn't normally be an issue, but when I do video editing you can literally hear (and see in the performance monitor) the computer getting up to speed when I'm cutting.

Comment: creative use of the "turbo" turbo 4 cores type is one of the OC methods, does not kick in until turbo does, so it kicks in when needed.  Got windows? Fire up the resource monitor and in the CPU section the top Bar will show "maximum frequency"  is it saying 100% or more than 100% ?   In control pannel Power, Make a custom "high performance" power profile , set Processor Power Managment min and max to 100%.  anything other than that simple stuff, one would have to know a Lot of the Bios/uefi settings you have made, to get your OC. Plus there are many other adjusts that can vary on boards.

Comment: You should not be having balking in a turbo transition anyways, could be even if you lock your system all up to max forever, that it does not solve the real issue your feeling.